# Error message "OpenCV: not authorized to capture video (status 0)" in MacOS QT

Tags: macos, qt, opencv, qt5

I know there were already some similar questions and it seems the question is not arose by OpenCV but by MacOS authority rule.

I have read some solutions, like create a Info.plist into source directory. And that works! But for me now only in Debug mode in QTCreator, not in Release mode. That is, when I run the program in Debug mode, everything is just OK. But in Release mode within QTCreator, the error message shows up:

```
OpenCV: not authorized to capture video (status 0), requesting...
16:12:22: The program has unexpectedly finished.
```

Some more strange informations. The program, say Test.app which is generated by QTCreator in Release or Debug mode, can be executed by directly double clicking on it or on the executable file residing in Test.app/Contents, after authorized for sure.

Additional System Information:

1. macOS Catalina Version 10.15.4
2. Qt 5.14.2
3. OpenCV 4.3.0

Also the Info.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE plist SYSTEM "file://localhost/System/Library/DTDs/PropertyList.dtd">
 <plist version="0.9">
     <dict>
        <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
        <string>uses camera to see vision targets</string>
    </dict>
 </plist>
```

Some codes may be helpful. FYI, the program crashes before the Camera class created.

```cpp
// camera.cpp
std::shared_ptr<Camera> Camera::Ptr = nullptr;

void Camera::CreateCamera()
{
  if(!Ptr)
    Ptr.reset(new Camera);
}

Camera::Camera()
  : _device(1)
{
}
bool Camera::GrabMerged(cv::Mat &img)
{
  if(_device.isOpened())
  {
    cv::Mat tmp;
    _device.read(tmp);
    if(tmp.empty())
    {
      qWarning("[Camera] Grab image failed.");
      return false;
    }
    qInfo("[Camera] merged image info: cols=%d, rows=%d, channels=%d, step0=%lu，step1=%lu, type=%d",
          tmp.cols, tmp.rows, tmp.channels(), tmp.step[0], tmp.step[1], tmp.type());
    cv::cvtColor(tmp, img, cv::COLOR_RGB2BGR);
    return true;
  }
  qCritical("[Camera] Camera is not opened.");
  return false;
}
...
```

```cpp
// camera.h
class Camera: public QObject
{
...
private:
  cv::VideoCapture _device;
...
}
```

Comment: could you show us some code involved ? on my side, I usually need to open the device several times on macos, the first time, it asks system for permission and it fails, then the second it succeed

Comment: @antoine Sure! I have revised the question with some useful codes. In my situation, it crashes every time in Release mode.

Comment: could you try to open the camera outside of the constructor ? I'm pretty sure that doing so rise an exception because the permission is not yet granted and doing so in a constructor crash the app. At least this is my understanding

Comment: @antoine I have tried to move open operation into a slot of button widget, call it 'Connect'. So program can be started from QTCreate IDE in release mode. But it still crashes when a click on Connect button (this will call _device.open() underlying). Error msg is the same as question title.

Comment: could your share a minimum project ready to build ? I can't reproduce that error despite I had it in the past few week even if I remove all plist files I can still run my test program even on another computer both in debug and release mode.

Comment: @antoine Finally, I create a minimum project which can reproduce that problem. Here is the GitHub link (https://github.com/WorstCodeWay/Test.git). Please check it.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't reproduce the error. I build your example and then I can open the executable in terminal and it doesn't ask for permission and open the camera when I click the button (in Debug). Then I tried to open the app bundle and it ask for permission when I click the button. Once the permission granted, I have to click a second time to open the cam, which is expected. I have the same behavior both in Release and Debug mode. btw I'm on macos 10.15.5 with opencv 4.3.0

Comment: @antoine So weird! Do you run the program from the QTCreator IDE by clicking 'Run' button with green triangle shape？ My error msg shows up in that way. If you do so. Then it may be caused by the macOS version? Mine is 10.15.4. And opencv is 4.3.0 too. I should try to update may macOS system.

Answer (score 1):

In case helpful for others.

Qt Creator > Projects > Run > Environment > add `OPENCV_AVFOUNDATION_SKIP_AUTH` `0` , then you will get the MacOS prompt "QtCreator wants to access the camera". I'm running macOS 11.4

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for taking time to push a [minimal project](https://github.com/WorstCodeWay/Test.git) that allow to reproduce the error.

After some test, it appears that this project works fine when started from command line or by double-clicking on the app bundle icon (both in Release and Debug mode). In the later case, system ask for permission to use the camera when clinking on the `open` button. Once permission is granted, we need to click again on the button, this is an expected behavior with OpenCV `VideoCapture` on macos.

But when I start it from Qt Creator, I had this weird message :

> dyld: Symbol not found: __cg_jpeg_resync_to_restart
>     Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
>     Expected in: /usr/local/lib/libJPEG.dylib
>     in /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
>     18:29:38: The program has unexpectedly finished.

This is not the same as yours but that shows that there is some difference between normal execution and execution from QtCreator.
And in my case, Qt Creator is the culprit.

And after disabling the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable under the Run environment (Projects Settings -> Run -> Environment), it works fine from QtCreator. Hourah !

My settings looks like : 
[image: Qt Creator settings]
This is with Qt Creator 4.12 / Qt 5.14.2 / OpenCV 4.3.0

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time. Now the problem is interesting. Your error message differs from mine. Mine is exact the same as question title described. I try to find variable what you've mentioned, but there's no such variable in my environment. But unexpected, I find a checkable button within Projects Settings -> Run , named "Run in terminal". I tried check it and now the program can be executed, asking for permission and everything goes fine. About this, I think it is just same way with running it from terminal. So problem seems unsolved. Don't know if it can be solved. Thank you again, antoine!

Comment: You're right this is not the same issue, I've updated my answer accordingly